# vue js filter search in b-table

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, bootstrap-vue

i display data using b-table , for the json i use this
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_page=1&_limit=5

here I display data with a limit of 5, on b-table i use filter or search function.

here I want to find an email with the name **Dallas@ole.me**, the email is on page 2, number 7
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_page=2&_limit=5

when I search for the email why can't it be found?

[image]

if i go to page 2 and search for the email it works
[image]

I hope that if I search for data on page 2 or 3, it can appear immediately, you don't have to go to pages 2 and 3 first.

this my code

```
<b-table class="table spacing-table" style="font-size: 13px;" 
show-empty :items="mydata" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="0"
:filter="filter"></b-table>

<b-pagination style="justify-content: center;" size="sm" :total-rows="totalItems" v-model="currentPage" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
```

and this

```
  return {
        filter: null,
        fields: [
         {
            key: 'id',
            label: 'item',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'name',
            label: 'item',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'email',
            label: 'item',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'body',
            label: 'item',
            sortable: true
         },
         { key: 'actions', label: 'Doc' }
         ],
         currentPage: 1,
         perPage: 5,
         totalItems: 0
      }
      created() {
       this.fetchData()
      },
      computed:{
       ...mapState(['mydata'])
      },
 methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      var start = this.currentPage;
      await this.$store.dispatch('getData', start).then(response => {
        this.totalItems = parseInt(response.headers['x-total-count'], 10)
        return response.data
        })
    },
    filterGrid(val){
        return !this.filter || JSON.stringify(val).includes(this.filter)
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As following the official documentation, default filtering just filters the current data array.

> Filtering, when used, is applied by default to the original items array data. b-table provides several options for how data is filtered.

So, as you are using server-side pagination, you will have to implement a custom filter so it can get the filtered data from your API.